# opening jupyter notebook in anaconda

Tags: jupyter

When I tried to install Anaconda into my computer, the destination folder for my installation was "C:\Users\Lara Nguyen\Anaconda3". When I clicked "Next", there was a pop-up saying that "Error:'Destination folder' contains 1 space. This can cause problems with several Conda packages, and is thus disabled. Please install to a path without a space". After the installation, opened cmd and typed "Jupyter Notebook" but there was an error message saying that:"jupyter"is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable command or batch file.

Is there anyway I can fix this problem?

Comment: were you able to successfully install anaconda ?

Comment: this cmd you run, is it from Anaconda prompt (Menu > Anaconda3 > Anaconda prompt or normal cmd)?

Answer (score 1):

- Looking at your path I am assuming you are using windows (I mention this so that other linux user do not refer this answer)
- First of all it's clearly mentioned in the Anaconda installation documents that it is recommended to install to a path which does not have spaces
- If you installed it correctly, did you register the anaconda path to the environment variable? If not then do that
- The paths that you have to register will be something like this:

  `C:User\username\Anaconda3`
  `C:User\username\Anaconda3\Scripts`
  `C:User\username\Anaconda3\Library`
- Now run the anaconda prompt (not cmd) and just type the `conda` commmand
- After typing the `conda` command if you did not get any error then you have successfully installed jupyter as well (You can cross check this by going to following location : `C:User\username\Anaconda3\Scripts` and searching for jupyter-script.py file)
- now in anaconda prompt itself run the command `jupyter notebook`
- if it still throws you error then I would strongly recommend you to reinstall Anaconda3 and follow the above steps correctly